# Can I import and sum values in google spreadsheets with easier?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a problem and can't find a good solution, maybe anyone could help?

I've got 8 similiar workbooks with employees working hours, each of them containing the same rows and columns yet with different values.

I need to import them to a new sheet/workbook and sum each row.
I'm using:

```
=SUM({IMPORTRANGE("KEY", "Sheet1!A1"),IMPORTRANGE("KEY2", "Sheet1!A1"),IMPORTRANGE("KEY3", "Sheet1!A1")})
```

This imports the values and sums them for each row.

Can anyone help me so I won't have to manually change the range for every row?

Comment: If you use `indirect` in your formulas, you can use a single cell in your master sheet to control the row being referenced in your formulas. Then to change rows you alter one cell, instead of every cell with a formula

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you import the workbooks data into eight different sheets of a new workbook and then, using another sheet, don't you make the sums?

Comment: Hi Nicola, i cant do that because every employee adds their working hours every week end i have to use different workbook, and event so, dont know how to import such amount off data without using importrange manually